# Seleccionar rango de columna de la izquierda con datos para usarlo con el mismo numero de filas en el de la derecha vacia

Tags: excel, vba

Después de mucho buscar estoy en un punto muerto, estoy intentando automatizar unos gráficos con datos en Excel, y para poder aliviar el peso y la agilidad de los datos tengo que ahorrar que las mas de 1 millón de líneas de una columna estén llenas de contenido "formulas".

Para lo cual necesito saber la cantidad de filas de la columna A para poder seleccionar ese numero de filas de la columna B, a partir de la B2 dado que la primera fila es el titulo.

Esto es lo que he conseguido de momento y no he sabido como continuar porque todo lo que pruebo me da error de compilación en la ultima linea.

'''

```
Dim filasvacias As Double
filasvacias = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
Dim filasdatos As Double
filasdatos = Range("A:A").Count
Dim filas As Integer
filas = filasdatos - filasvacias

Range("B2:B" & filas).Select
```

'''

Os agradezco mucho vuestra ayuda :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leyendo tu pregunta mencionas *tengo que ahorrar que las mas de 1 millón de líneas de una columna estén llenas de contenido "formulas"*. Entiendo que lo que quieres es copiar y pegar valores de la columna B.

Si solo quieres eso, no te compliques y haz únicamente:

```
Range("B:B") = Range("B:B").Value
```

Esto transformará **todas** las fórmulas de la columna B en valores, es decir, como si los hubieras escrito a mano. Y lo que ya fuera un valor (un encabezado, por ejemplo), permanecerá exactamente igual.

Si quieres hacer esto mismo, pero solo desde B2 hasta la última celda no vacía de la columna B, la respuesta de @dogwall te sirve perfectamente para eso.

Respecto a tu código, dices que te da error, pero no especificas qué error es. Viendo tu código, es de desbordamiento seguro. Tus variables `filasvacias` y `filasdatos` las declaras de tipo `Long`. Eso es correcto. Pero luego declaras `filas` como `Integer`, cuyo valor máximo es algo más de 32.000. La operación que tú haces es `flasdatos - filasvacias`. Si el resultado es mayor 32.000, entonces dará error.

Puedes ver los tipos de datos aquí (**muy importantes** para programar):

> [Resumen de tipo de
> datos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

PD: El intervalo exacto de `Integer` es (-32768 ; 32767). Yo puse 32.000 porque es más fácil para escribir y asimilar el contexto, pero no es preciso.

Answer (score 4):

No termino de entender la lógica de lo que buscas pero bueno, prueba con esto:

```
Sub test()

    Dim filasvacias As Long
    Dim filas As Long
    Dim filasdatos As Long
    Dim ult_fila as Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    'Defino mi hoja de trabajo
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
    
    'Obtengo la última fila de la columna A
    ult_fila = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Total filas sin datos en columna A
    filasvacias = sht.Range("A2:A" & ult_fila).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    'Total de filas columna A
    filasdatos = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    filas = filasdatos - filasvacias
    
    'Selecciono filas de la columna B
    sht.Range("B2:B" & filas).Select

End Sub
```